# Can Cesium map run on Apache HTTP server instead of node.js environment?

Tags: node.js, apache, cesiumjs

I have an Apache HTTP server that handles all my requests for a Ruby on Rails project.  We are thinking of adding a Cesium map component.  I am wondering if I can run Cesium on the Apache HTTP server instead of setting up a node.js environment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Cesium is completely client-side and can be served by any HTML server.

Answer (score 1):

I have it running in JBoss. All I did was take the contents of the ZIP file and dropped them into the deploy area of JBoss under a Cesium.war directory.

Works like a champ...