# Hosting Cesium Map on apache tomcat

Tags: tomcat, cesiumjs

I am new to Cesium 3D Map js. I want to integrate this with my existing application which uses apache tomcat as web server. i want to host cesium using this instead of node.js.

On there [Getting Started](https://cesiumjs.org/tutorials/cesium-up-and-running) tutorial and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21561869/can-cesium-map-run-on-apache-http-server-instead-of-node-js-environment), they have written that you just have to unzip the cesium.zip file and host it in your server.

I unziped the cesium.zip file in a folder named CesiumRoot, then i just dropped  in the webapps folder of apache and started my server. But it didn't worked. 
I searched for it this problem and found nothing.

Please tell a procedure or any tutorial which tells how to host it in apache.

Comment: Does it give you an error message?  Can you check the browser console and post any related error messages found there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deploy Cesium in Tomcat or a web-container other than node.js, you must unzip the Cesium distribution in the context of the webapp so the HTML pages, servlets, jsps, etc. can resolve the URLs to cesium resources as relative URLs.

Given a test page *test.html* with the Cesium package in a folder named "Cesium", the test.html page would refer to Cesium resources as following:

```
  <script src="Cesium/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Cesium/Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css">
```

First, start with a simple hello world app to get started.
Here is the full contents of test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Use correct character set. -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- Tell IE to use the latest, best version. -->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <!-- Make the application on mobile take up the full browser screen and disable user scaling. -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>Hello World!</title>  
  <script src="Cesium/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Cesium/Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css">
  <style>      
      html, body, #cesiumContainer {
          width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden;
      }
  </style>
</head> 
<body>
 <div id="cesiumContainer"></div>
 <script>

 var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer'); 

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what if I Dont have an internet connection.

1. How can I host cesium using apache in offline mode?
2. Also is this procedure same for every Os. I am using rhel7. Will it be same for rhel and windows?

Comment: With no internet connection cesium can still work standalone but you will need a local image and/or terrain server to host the base map imagery and terrain.

Comment: I tried as you said but it is not working. I unzipped the contents in a folder named "Cesium" and put it in the webapps folder of tomcat, and started the server, but it doesn't get hosted. There is no error in the console also. 
What could be the issue for not getting hosted.

There isn't any tutorial for this. i am not able to find anything.

Comment: Need to check error message in web console. First, try to resolve issues trying to resolve URLs to the cesium javascript and CSS. No official tutorial for this.